# Xamarin : Adding condition inside isvisible in xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new with xamarin, I am facing an issue in my xamarin forms project.
I have an  inside listview-viewcell, having 250 width and height.
Sometimes the value of mediaUrl is null. I want to hide the Image for null mediaUrl values and make visible for other values.
My problem is if the value of the mediaUrl is null showing blank space in the UI. Inside isVisible property how can I apply this condition?
My code is giving below:

```
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Image
                            WidthRequest="250"
                            HeightRequest="250"
                            Source="{Binding mediaUrl}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>           
    </StackLayout>
```

Anybody please suggest a solution with working code.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use trigger for that

```
<Image.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding isMediaUrlNull}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
      </DataTrigger>
 </Image.Triggers>
```

**Edit**

You can also add property in model `isMediaUrlNull` and try above code

```
public bool isMediaUrlNull {get {return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaUrl);}}

<Image WidthRequest="250" HeightRequest="250" IsVisible="{Binding mediaUrl}" Source="{Binding mediaUrl}"/>
```

Comment: Apply triggers, getting error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Position 91:98. Type NULL not found in xmlns http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml SmartTweet F:\BackUp - Copy\SmartTweet\SmartTweet\Pages\DashBoardPage.xaml 91

Comment: When i add "public bool isMediaUrlNull { get { string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaUrl)} }" code to model getting not all code paths return a value error.

Comment: is mediaUrl string type?

Comment: sorry my mistake forgot to put return. see update code

Comment: I forget to add the <Image> before  <Image.Triggers>
Now blank space are hide, but images are not loading if the mediaurl value is not null

Comment: If you have a isMediaUrlNull property, why not just bind that directly to IsVisible?

Comment: Current code:
<Image
                                    WidthRequest="250"
                                        HeightRequest="250">
                                <Image.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding isMediaUrlNull}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Image.Triggers>
                                </Image>

Comment: I don't have isMediaUrlNull property

Comment: Binding="{Binding isMediaUrlNull}"

Comment: Where I need to add this code Binding="{Binding isMediaUrlNull}", inside <Image>, <Image.Triggers> or <DataTrigger>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159209/discussion-between-steve-chadbourne-and-edwiser).

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this using a value converter

Create a converter like this

```
public class NullToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This will return false if the value is null

Register it in your page like this

```
<ContentPage
   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yourNameSpaceToWhereYourConverteClassIs"
   x:Class="yourNameSpace.Views.MyPage">
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:NullToBoolConverter x:Key="NullToBoolConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Then add it like this

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Image
                            WidthRequest="250"
                            HeightRequest="250"
                            Source="{Binding mediaUrl}"
                            IsVisible={Binding mediaUrl, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}}/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>           
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: When I add <ContentPage.Resources> in xaml, showing an error 'local' is an undeclared prefix. I added <ContentPage.Resources> above of listview.

Answer (score 0):

the solution of Steve Chadbourne is good.

you should declare the converter this :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SAMPLE.Sample">

<!--RESOURCES-->
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:NullToBoolConverter x:Key="NullToBoolConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView >
        Use Converter
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```